# Prefix 0 in a Phone number string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a phone number in sql table, i want to add prefix '0' where ever phone number is 10 digit,
but if it is less than 10 or greater than 10 digit then no 0 prefix required.

```
7863176061
7724269820
2088076157
1992762084
1318912
```

**output**

```
07863176061
07724269820
02088076157
01992762084
1318912
```

Comment: It sounds like you're storing phone numbers using an inappropriate data type. You don't do maths on phone numbers, or perform numeric comparisons. This means they shouldn't be stored in a numeric column but instead as a *string* - with, if you wish, a constraint to ensure it only contains digits. Once you're using the correct data type, storing the leading zero becomes possible and then you don't have to write code to "correct" the phone numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression to check the length.

**Query**

```
select 
  case when len([phone_number]) = 10 
  then '0' + cast([phone_number] as varchar(20)) 
  else cast([phone_number] as varchar(20)) end
from [your_table_name];
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/637957/prefix-0-in-a-phone-number-string-sql)**

You have to cast the phone number column to varchar if the column datatype is in bigint. Otherwise you can exclude the cast part in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select 
   case when len(yourcolumn) =10 
   then '0'+ yourcolumn 
   else yourcolumn end as column 
 from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE LEN(Num) WHEN  10 THEN '0'+cast(Num as varchar(11)) ELSE Num END AS Num
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will be fast,

```
select 

   '0' + cast([phone_number] as varchar(20)) 

from [your_table_name]
where len([phone_number]) = 10 ;
```